# Email and Black Hole List Submission?

Tags: email, spam

I'm having trouble with a spammer and would like to begin submitting their messages to a few black hole lists.

Unfortunately, I'm having trouble finding a list. For example mail-abuse.org now redirects to Trend Micros and there's nothing of substance available (just a dashboard showing SPAM densities per country).

Are there any black hole lists remaining that accept submissions? What is state of the art in protection from targeted email?

Comment: Individual emails can be reported to entities like [KnujOn](http://www.knujon.com/sendusspam.html) and [SpamCop](https://www.spamcop.net/).  If you have a *feed* of spams, you could configure it to automatically forward to entities like SpamCop.  Please **contact the SpamCop deputies if you want to donate a spam feed** (use the [SpamCop contact form](https://www.spamcop.net/fom-serve/cache/401.html), and put something like "donating a spam trap" in *Other reasons for contact*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not used any of these myself but there are a few:

- https://blackholemx.abusix.com/
- http://www.sorbs.net/listing/submission.shtml
- http://www.barracudacentral.org/rbl/how-to-use
- http://www.spamhaus.org/faq/section/DNSBL%20Usage

State of the art protection is about blocking transmission as far upstream as you can. Ensure that you can blacklist as close to the edge of your network as possible. Better still get a specialist to handle you incoming mail before it gets to your network & only pass you cleansed email.

Our own stats from a 12k user system shows many millions of spam messages per month though we are probably a larger target than most.

Comment: This answer contains directions for using [DNSBL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNSBL)s (a.k.a. "Black Hole Lists").  My understanding of the question is that it requests a method to *help* DNSBLs by submitting data to them.  Only the SORBS link in this answer accomplishes that.